# Allign file based on field values

Tags: awk

I have a file like below with two fields ending with *.alarms.gz and *.values.gz, want to allign the files like all the alarms.gz in first field and all the values.gz in second field. How can i achieve this.

**Sample Input**

```
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412_92E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz               20190412.alarms.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_42E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_32E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
    20190412.alarms.gz              20190412_12E1EA3400B1CFA1.values.gz
```

**Required output**

```
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_02E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190412_92E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz               
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_42E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190415_32E9EA3400B1CF41.values.gz
20190412.alarms.gz              20190412_12E1EA3400B1CFA1.values.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` match only those lines that are off the grid, i.e. `values` in `$1` and `alarms` in `$2` and swap the column values. The `{..}1` re-constructs the whole line with any modifications done inside the `{..}` and any change to the field/record separators.

```
awk '$1 ~ /.*values.gz/ && $2 ~ /.*alarms.gz/ { tmp = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = tmp }1' file | 
column -t
```

The part `column -t` is just for pretty printing the output of `awk`. You could use the `printf()` with appropriate widths, but the former command makes the job easier.

But on a POSIX complaint only `awk`, use `printf()`

```
awk '$1 ~ /.*values.gz/ && $2 ~ /.*alarms.gz/ { tmp = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = tmp; } 
{ printf "%s%40s\n",$1,$2}' file
```

If you were to make the changes in-line and using GNU `awk` less than 4.1.2, use a temporary file for re-direct the contents out of it

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

awk '$1 ~ /.*values.gz/ && $2 ~ /.*alarms.gz/ { tmp = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = tmp }1' file | 
column -t > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" file
```

or use the magical `sponge` tool from moreutils package ( On RHEL, do `yum install moreutils`)

```
awk '$1 ~ /.*values.gz/ && $2 ~ /.*alarms.gz/ { tmp = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = tmp }1' file | 
column -t | 
sponge file
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks !!!. What does 1 in the last part   of the 1 before single quotes means.

Comment: 1 is used for print.  awk '{print}' file is equal to awk '1' file